# Blackberry: How to get a particular parameter/variable from php in java?

Tags: php, variables, blackberry

I'm new to php. Please can anyone guide me through this? I have a php where I'm having some variables as sort of flags. When those flags are set/true, I start those services in my Blackberry otherwise not. My application keeps on listening to my php and when those flags are true, it starts the respective services, others are kept off. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is designed to answer [specific programming questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). Your question is far too vague and suggests little in the way of prior research or effort on your part. I've voted to close.

Comment: ^ as above. Also, create an API of some sort probably

Comment: I was just asking for 2 lines of code: how to send variable in php to java, and how to receive variable at Java side. Anyways, I'm using the code below for sending 1 variable, and I'm getting the server response at Java side. But I don't know how to send multiple variables from php so that I've to code minimum. My code:
<?php
$var = "1";

if($var=="1")
{
    echo $var;
} 
else
echo "Continue to run";
?>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want push notifications.

If you do it by "listening" to a php page, you're going to have to repeatedly make requests to that php page.  You could do long-polling, but that's not going to work very well on a cell phone... each time the connection disconnects, you need to connect again, and it's messy to write all that client side code yourself.  PHP also isn't a great language for push notifications, because on the web-server side, there's no easy way to push information to php once php has a connection from your blackberry.  Since PHP isn't multithreaded (in typical webserver configurations), you'll again most likely be busy-polling some notification in a file on the disk of the web server, rather than just receiving and handling a notification as from a message queue or socket/io connection.

Most phone development kits have built in APIs to handle push notifications.  From what I understand, re-using these systems leverages existing architecture, meaning the phone only connects to one server, which saves battery life.

I've never done any blackberry development, but you should probably start by searching for information/tutorials on implementing push notifications in blackberry.

If I'm wrong, and you just want to be able to get configuration options for your blackberry app, then that's easy.  Your php page just spits out the information in any format the client (blackberry) can read (like json, xml, key=value, whatever), blackberry parses it, and acts on it.